# Blue prism- Getting "Cannot create ActiveX component." error when interacting with Excel VOB operations

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

I am doing a basic exploration on RPA using Blue prism. When I interacting with Excel VBO operation (Create instance) BP throwing following error.

> Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by
>   code stage: Cannot create ActiveX component.

**Object flow:**

1. Start
2. Create instance
3. Open work book
4. Get worksheet as collection

**Steps tried to resolve the issue:**
Re registered exes both excel and blue prism but no luck.

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: Can you execute the steps manually?

Comment: Yeah, I can initiate excel without any problem.

Comment: I've never used "Create instance". Allways went for OpenWorkbook and I never had any problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by following the below steps:

Actually this is happening because I've JAB dll's in various locations. You have to delete all the JAB file which is there in the following locations and by executing the following commend you can see all Jab related files sitting in your machine.

```
dir c:\*ccess*ridge*.dll, c:\*ccess*ridge*.jar, c:\accessibility.properties /s /b
```

**Locations where all JAB files needs to be removed:**

1. Windows32
2. SysWOW64
3. Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate

**This solution will work for only 64-bit windows 7 or higher version of OS**

1)Make sure you have installed jre 1.7 or higher version (1.7+ version will have JAB in build, so you don't need to install it externally)

2)Maker sure you have pasted below files under "Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate" Copy these files from installed jre\bin

- JavaAccessBridge-64.dll
- JAWTAccessBridge-64.dll
- WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll

3) Enable JAB from windows control panel.

Now try to spy any java application. It should be working. Cheers!! :)

Comment: From my experience, using the 'C:\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate' folder as prefered path for DLL's is risky. This path is used as long as you debug and develop. When working on production environment and using a client on external computers/VDIs, this folder will not be used. So it's better to use Environmental Variables paths as this will work on both debug and client run processes.

Comment: What does the java Access bridge have to do with Excel Automation?

Comment: @FrankJelstrup You shouldn't have to copy these DLLs to the BP Automate folder. It should already be in your path as a result of the java install.